# WordPress admin_enqueue_scripts not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this code below and it seems not working:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

But when I replace it with **wp_enqueue_scripts** instead of **admin_enqueue_scripts** then it will load the file.
I'm not sure what's the issue.

Answer (score 5):

**admin_enqueue_scripts()** only fires in your back-end admin area (/wp-admin/) - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

**wp_enqueue_scripts()** is used to properly enqueue scripts in front-end (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

So if your want load stuff in front-end wp_enqueue_scripts() is the way to go.

Cheers

Comment: @FrancesoCarlucci, I'm planning to use the admin admin_enqueue_scripts() because I need to view the imported fonts being displayed on some slider plugin during edits or previews. But it seems that it's not applying the fonts I imported through css file. So my question is, if I were to use the admin_enqueue_scripts(), is it also inserting a link tag in the DOM like what wp_enqueue_scripts() do? Because I don't see it unless I use the wp_enqueue_scripts().

Comment: Yes that's what admin_enqueue_scripts() does. If its not working problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: You're right @FrancesoCarlucci, my bad I searched the DOM in frontend instead inside the dashboard. Now I can see the imported file and my issue has been resolved. I think I just had a wrong import url. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 4):

**add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );**
this is use for the backend side work.

**add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );**
this is use for front-end side work.